# App to server security: How can I authenticate an Android app/user on my server?

Tags: php, android, http-post

I am building an app that will not use a login. It involves users making requests to a server where information is stored, and that information can then be sent to other users via HTTP post. What I am wondering is how can I ensure that post requests going to the server are coming from the app and not from some other device sending artificial posts?

Comment: app sends secret 'im the app' key with each request. preferably dynamic

Comment: It wouldn't be secure to just have the key present in the source of the app, right? If it's decompiled?

Comment: that would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that you can't. You need to add per-user authentication or some other input that is not stored anywhere on the device.